# Stop popup from scaling - react leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have added some popups on my map in leaflet using react and was wondering if there was a way to stop them from scaling when the user zooms in and out of the map. I basically want to keep them and the text inside of them at their size of when the map is fully zoomed in even when the map is fully zoomed out. I am fairly new to coding but tried using different leaflet components and different css options but nothing worked.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean 'scaling'?  Popups and markers stay the same size regardless of zoom level...?

Comment: that's exactly my problem, I don't want them to stay the same size regardless of zoom. I want them to become large when zoomed in and small when zoomed out. Not sure it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but not through use of `<Marker />`.  You have to do it as an `<ImageOverlay />`.  Look into [`L.imageOverlay`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#imageoverlay) to learn about how it works and check out [`ImageOverlay`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components#imageoverlay) to see how react-leaflet implements it.  You can use these [colored marker images](https://github.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers) as the source of the ImageLayer.

As far as a popup goes, you would probably need to use the `className` prop on the `<Popup /`> and have it dynamically respond to the current zoom level of the map so that it scales according to zoom.  Or take a picture of the popup and include it in your source image for the `ImageOverlay`.